# Interview ques : Sorting 20 GB data

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given 20 GB of data (normally numbers) and you have only 1GB of RAM, How will you sort the data?

Comment: The question does not seem as bad, but you should also post your own thoughts and the efforts you took to solve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interview puzzle: Sorting a million number input with limited memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775784/interview-puzzle-sorting-a-million-number-input-with-limited-memory). The numbers are different, but I don't believe that affects the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Sort 20 groups of numbers and write them to disk. Once their sorted read from all groups simultaneously using a buffer and print out the ordered master set. For this last merge step you should only need constant memory.